# Override default implementations for derived typeclass instances

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc

I have defined a datatype for which I allow GHC to automatically derive an instance of the `Eq typeclass`.

However, the derived instance doesn't have the precise behavior I need for all cases.

For instance, see this datatype:

```
data IntegerOrFloat = I Integer | F Float
  deriving Eq
```

`(I 0) == (F 0)` evaluates to `False`. I would like it to evaluate to true. If I were writing the implementation I could simply do:

```
instance Eq IntegerOrFloat where
  (I i) == (F f) = (fromIntegral i) == f
```

However, I would then have to write the other three cases. Obviously this would be trivial for this type, but this is a contrived example. I very much prefer the convenience of leaving most cases automatically derived.

Is there a way for me to "override" the derived implementation for a specific case, without having to write the entire implementation by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`generic-deriving`** package [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving), this makes implementations for types that are a member of the `Generic` type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Generics.Deriving.Base(Generic)
import Generics.Deriving.Eq(GEq, geq)

data IntegerOrFloat = I Integer | F Float
  deriving (Generic)

instance GEq IntegerOrFloat

instance Eq IntegerOrFloat where
    F f == I i = fromIntegral i == f
    I i == F f = fromIntegral i == f
    x == y = geq x y
```

[**`geq :: GEq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.14/docs/Generics-Deriving-Eq.html#v:geq) is thus an instance that automatically generate an `(==)` function like Haskell does this, we can then use `geq` this as a base function.

Answer (score 3):

You could leave the derived type as-is, but export only a newtype-wrapped version that has the special case overridden:

```
data IntegerOrFloat' = I' Integer | F' Float
  deriving Eq

newtype IntegerOrFloat = IOF { getIOF :: IntegerOrFloat' }

instance Eq IntegerOrFloat where
  IOF (I i) == IOF (F f) = fromIntegral i == f
  IOF (F f) == IOF (I i) = f == fromIntegral i
  IOF x == IOF y = x==y
```

But I really find this rather dubious. If you need different `Eq` behaviour, then you should probably implement everything completely by hand – different `Eq` instance means pretty much everything should treat `F 0` and `I 0` as if they were the same value, which is not what the compiler assumes with derived instances.

Comment: I really want a `deriving stock for newtype` mechanism. Most commonly, I want to derive all the `Foldable` methods except for `length`. `generic-deriving` only does `foldMap` and that's not always enough.